# Trying to sort an NSMutableDictionary by values using @selector in iOS

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, selector, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains keys that are `NSString`s, and values that are objects of type "Fraction".  This is a custom object that I have created and is exactly what it is, Fractions that are composed of a numerator, and a denominator (each one is an int).  What I would like to do is get an array of the values (in this case, "Fraction" objects) from the `NSMutableDictionary`, and then sort the array using `@selector` as follows:

```
NSArray *myFractions = [myDict allValues];
NSArray *sortedFractions = [myFractions sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(comparator)];
```

or

```
NSArray *myFractions = [myDict allValues];
NSArray *sortedFractions = [myFractions sortedArrayUsingFunction:comparatorFunction context:nil];
```

My question is, how do I create a comparatorFunction method that will sort the "Fraction" objects in order of biggest, to smallest?  Please remember that each "Fraction" object is composed of two variables: a numerator of type int, and a denominator that is also of type int.

This question is different from others that have been posted because here I am asking about how, within the "sortedArrayUsingFunction" method I am to sort the "Fraction" objects from greatest to least.  The other questions that were thought to be duplicates were looking at sorting based on NSDate objects, or based on NSString values, whereas mine is different.  As I said,  I am very new to this, and needed something much more specific.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stylistic improvement, can I suggest you to use a closure instead of a function? To sort the objects in descending order, simply compare their actual numerical value, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = // dictionary of NSString keys and Fraction values
NSArray *fractions = [dict allValues];

NSArray *sortedFractions = [fractions sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    Fraction *f1 = obj1;
    Fraction *f2 = obj2;
    double diff = (double)(f1.num) / f1.denom - (double)(f2.num) / f2.denom;
    return diff < 0 ? NSOrderedAscending : diff > 0 ? NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  Shouldn't it be [dict allValues] instead of [dict allObjects]?

Comment: @syedfa It certainly should.

Comment: Thanks very much BiCarbonate, your solution worked!

Comment: @syedfa, just a chemistry aside here. Bicarbonate is HCO3-, H2CO3 is carbonic acid.

Comment: @rdelmar Chemists to the rescue!

Comment: @rdelmar: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In your class you need to implement a method similar to this :

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compareFirstName:(Fraction *)fraction{

      return ((float)self.numerator/self.denominator > (float)fraction.numerator/fraction.denominator);
}
```

**Not compiled and checked*

Comment: What are those calls to `objectAtIndex:` and `compare:` on a `float`?

Comment: oops it should be directly > or < , i missed that this is a primitive :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidyia Still, what is `objectAtIndex:` doing there?

Comment: @H2CO3: is it still wrong or makes some sense ? :(

Comment: It's good now. [15 chars]

Comment: @H2CO3: now what is 15 chars?

Comment: A brainless restriction by SO on comments. "It's good now" can't be posted as a comment, because it's not at least 15 chars, so I had to write some garbage to make it long enough to make SO enable me to post it.